# Exclude page from https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https

I have an iFrame on https page that points to a HTTP page. As a result, 
the new HTTPs page will not display the iFrame. I wish to exclude the page which holds the iframe from https so the iFrame will show.

My current .htaccess file to redirect http to https is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on  
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: In >95% of all cases it is better to proxy the content you reference inside that iframe via your server.

Comment: could you please provide an example?

Comment: An example for what? For how to proxy content? Just take a look at the documentation of apaches proxy module. It is 2 lines of code you need in the end, maybe even only one, and you can server your _whole_ page via the https protocol.

Comment: a link through a proxy? I will test. Thanks